# In how many ways can you distribute 9 different objects among 5 persons A,B,C,D,E, at least one object to each, and $n_{A} > n_{B}$?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

My attempt:

There are 6 ways to distribute the 9 objects such that $n_{A} > n_{B}$.

Here, the first number is $n_{A}$, and second number is $n_{B}$

They are:
$51111,
42111,
31113,
32112,
21222$

For convenience's sake, let ${n \choose r}$ be $^nC_r$

$51111$ - $^9C_5 \times ^4C_4 \times 4! = 3024$

$42111$ - After selecting 4 objects for A, we can select either 1 or 2 objects for B, so no matter how many objects we choose, $n_{A} > n_{B}$ is always satisfied.

$42111$ - $^9C_{4} \times ^5C_{3} \times ^2C_{2} \times 4! = 30240$

$31113$ - $^9C_{3} \times ^6C_{3} \times ^3C_{3} \times 3! = 10080$

$32112$ - $^9C_{3} \times ^6C_{4} \times ^2C_{2} \times 4! = 30240$

$21222$ - $^9C_{2} \times ^7C_{1} \times ^6C_{6} \times 3! = 1512$

The total sum is 75096.

But I'm not very sure of this answer. This problem seems trickier than meets the eye. How do you solve it?

Comment: hint: calculate the situation where $n_a=n_b$, then when you subtract it from total, tha half will be $n_a > n_b$

Comment: @NotaSalmonFish I seem to be having a bit of trouble in applying this. I understand I have to add all the cases, but the restrictions on $n_{a} > n_{b}$ and permuting the elements of b, c, d and e seem to confuse me! Could you explain how what I have done is wrong?